# Netty - Sending POST requests

Tags: netty

Here's my situation:

1. Client sends a POST request to Netty Server.
2. Netty processes the POST request and 
    If the server determines that a response needs to be sent
      It sends a response back to the client.
    Else
       The server has to send a POST request to another end point, get the response and send that response back to the client.

So far I have got the incoming POST request working. To send the outgoing POST request this is what I'm doing in my Handler.

```
private void sendHttpPost(String input, ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        try {
            String url = "http://localhost";
            URI uri = new URI(url);
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(new NioEventLoopGroup())
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .handler(new PostRequestHandler())
            .option(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false);
           Channel f = b.connect("REMOTE_HOST", 8888).sync().channel();       
           HttpRequest postReq = new DefaultHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, 
                                        HttpMethod.POST, uri.getRawPath());
           postReq.headers().set(HttpHeaders.Names.HOST, "localhost");
           postReq.headers().set(HttpHeaders.Names.CONNECTION, HttpHeaders.Values.CLOSE);
           postReq.headers().set(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
           f.writeAndFlush(postReq);

           // Wait for the server to close the connection.
           f.closeFuture().sync();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
```

This is obviously wrong because I'm starting a new Bootstrap process within the handler. However, I can't send a HttpRequest without a channel. I can't reuse the existing Channel in the ChannelHandlerContext.

What's the correct way to do this ? How can I fork a new HttpPostRequest. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't use the existing channel to connect to another server since that channel already connected with your original client.I don't see anything wrong with this code. And as per your requirement, bootstrapping a client in server's handler is quite ok. You got this program work right?

Comment: @Sudheera I do get an unsupportedoperation exception and this code doesn't work                                      .java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doConnect(NioServerSocketChannel.java:135)
 at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.connect(AbstractNioChannel.java:172)
 at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadHandler.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1003)
 at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect0(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:527)
(can't paste the full stack trace)

Comment: can you post the  full handler class here?

Comment: Here't the URL with the full handler  http://pastebin.com/jPARd1z8

Comment: sorry I didn't spotted this before but the address `"REMOTE_HOST"` is wrong i guess..?

Comment: Yep, I thought about the same but replacing REMOTE_HOST with any string such as "localhost' or "127.0.0.1" still gives the same exception man. Also the exception trace is all within io.netty so can't even make out which line is causing the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.channel(NioSocketChannel.class)` instead of `.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)` in your client bootstrap code. That's it.